# one image path for development and production, Angular build

Tags: angular

I can't find out what path to use so my images work on dev and production, right now I can only get it to work on dev localhost. When I make a

> ng build --prod --output-path docs --base-href /haufe-beers/

the images do not show on my github pages hosted app.

This is the src path to show my image in development, it works in dev but fails in build version:

```
<img src="../../../assets/20190706_163735.jpg" alt="" width="200" />
```

What is the path to show for dev and prod? Something to do with base href but I can't get it to work?

Comment: You can also configure base url path in `environment` file

Comment: Try `<img src="assets/image.png">`. This can work for both dev and build.

Comment: You can check https://angular.io/api/common/APP_BASE_HREF

Answer (score 0):

after I created

> --base-href /haufe-beers/

in the ng build, I just added

> "./assets/xxxxx

It seems that Angular then uses that base to link paths from your prod build folder, in my case inside

> docs/assets

Its working now on dev and prod with:

```
<img src="./assets/20190706_163735.jpg" alt="" width="200" />
```